# Copy PDF file from Google drive to remote server

Tags: google-drive-api

I've built nice browsing window which shows all of the pdf files on my (or any user) Google Drive for managing purposes.

What i looking to do is simple, i want to take a pdf file from my google drive (i have all the info related to this file - "downloadUrl","webContentLink" etc) and just copy it to my server (remote).

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you already have the downlosdUrl of the pdf what's stopping you from saving it anywhere you want?

Comment: I can download it with no problem, but i want to fetch it to my server, and since the downlosdUrl is not a direct url with ending format .PDF i can't get to it's content or fetch it with "copy/file_get_content", am i missing here something ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm pretty late here, but this may help other people too.

You could try using Grive. Here's a straightforward tutorial: http://xmodulo.com/2013/05/how-to-sync-google-drive-from-the-command-line-on-linux.html

Even if you don't have root access on the server, you can simply build from source, and:

```
$ mkdir ~/google_drive
$ cd ~/google_drive
$ grive -a
```

You'll receive an auth URL which you need to paste on your browser and click on "Allow Access" and you're done. Go to the google_drive dir on your server and run `grive` to sync between your local dir and your GDrive.